# Return Table Object from Stored JSON in a Column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am sorry, I know this has been asked a billion times but I have tried to put together CROSS APPLY statements without any luck and needs some help. I have this data in SQL in a single column which I can get to by select column from table where id = blah:

> [
>     {
>       "User": "Bob",
>       "Domain": "DOMAIN",
>       "Sid": "S-1-5-21-3434343-3434343434-34343343434-242210"
>     },
>     {
>       "User": "adm-Bob",
>       "Domain": "DOMAIN",
>       "Sid": "S-1-5-21-34343434-3434343434-3434334-242240"
>     }
>   ]

How do I turn it into a table with three columns and two roles? I can do this when there is only one record in the JSON but I am failing to figure it out when there is more then one account in the JSON.

Comment: *"I have tried to put together CROSS APPLY statements without any luck"* Please do show us your attempt(s), without them how can we show you where you went wrong? I ***assume*** you're using SQL Server 2016+ too?

Comment: Sorry will do next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you tried, I can't tell you where you went wrong, but `OPENJSON` and a `WITH` works fine here:

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = '[ { "User": "Bob", "Domain": "DOMAIN", "Sid": "S-1-5-21-3434343-3434343434-34343343434-242210" }, { "User": "adm-Bob", "Domain": "DOMAIN", "Sid": "S-1-5-21-34343434-3434343434-3434334-242240" } ]';

SELECT OJ.[User],
       OJ.Domain,
       OJ.[Sid]
FROM (VALUES(@JSON))V(JSON)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.JSON) 
     WITH ([User] nvarchar(100) '$.User',
           Domain nvarchar(100) '$.Domain',
           [Sid] nvarchar(100) '$.Sid') OJ;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f977b742253bfbe98e903d157d25c1d2)

Comment: Specifying the path explicitly is actually optional if the column name matches the property name, so you could leave them out. (Of course, spelling them out still isn't wrong.)

Comment: Didn't know that one, @JeroenMostert, thanks for the extra detail.

Comment: Yup, I tried yesterday but was too soon. Thanks agian